# SonarQube does not start on windows even though path variables were set

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

My jdk version is 1.7.0. I searched answer but I don't find correct answer yet.This is error I have got. Plaese help me to solve the problem.

```
C:\sonarqube-5.6\bin\windows-x86-64>StartSonar.bat
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: Unable to locate the class  org.sonar.application.App: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:  org/sonar/application/App : Unsupport
ed major.minor version 52.0
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp Usage:
jvm 1    |   java org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp {app_class} [app_a
 rguments]
 jvm 1    |
 jvm 1    | Where:
 jvm 1    |   app_class:      The fully qualified class name of the application t
 o run.
 jvm 1    |   app_arguments:  The arguments that would normally be passed to      the
jvm 1    |                   application. 
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Your version of sonarqube requires Java 8 (`UnsupportedClassVersionError ... Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`)

Comment: Thank you. It means I have get minor version of SonarQube.

Comment: Which version of sonarQube do you use?

Comment: @WiranjiDinelka please keep in mind that Java 7 reach end of life in April *2015*, it is therefore strongly recommended to update to java 8.

Answer (score 6):

**SonarQube 5.6 (LTS *) – Jun. 3, 2016**
Long Term Supported version, requires Java 8 to run

Version from **SonarQube 5.1.2**  to **SonarQube 5.5**
Should work fine with Java 7